# Spring Data, fetching rows ManyToOne / OneToMany relationships?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a Spring project using Spring data. I have the following models :

**Location.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "location")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Location {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String latitude;

    private String longitude;

    private String date;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name ="user")
    @JsonBackReference
    private User user;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int uid;
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private boolean enabled;
    private String avatar;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "user_role")
    private Role role;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Location> locations;

    public int getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(int uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public List<Location> getLocations() {
        return locations;
    }

    public void setLocations(List<Location> locations) {
        this.locations = locations;
    }

}
```

**Database**

```
CREATE TABLE location (
id integer NOT NULL,
"user" integer,
...
CONSTRAINT location_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT location_user_fkey FOREIGN KEY ("user")
    REFERENCES users (uid) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE users
(
uid integer NOT NULL,
...
CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (uid)
)
```

**Goal** Using a CrudRepository, i want to fetch a list of all Locations WITH or WITHOUT corresponsing users !

```
public interface LocationRepository extends CrudRepository<Location, Integer> {

    List<Location> findAll();

    @Query("SELECT l FROM Location l")
    List<Location> findLast();

}
```

So as i understand the above Query will get all the Locations without the corresponding users, but the following

```
@Query("SELECT l FROM Location l JOIN l.user u")
```

will get all the locations WITH the corresponding users

**Problem: Both queries get all the Locations with the corresonding Users !**

What am i doing wrong here ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're mapping the `Location` to always retrieve `User` (and vice versa). If you don't want this behavior, you can mark to fetch the `User` in lazy way using [`FetchType.LAZY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/FetchType.html#LAZY):

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name ="user")
@JsonBackReference
private User user;
```

This way, `User user` in `Location` will only be retrieved when being accessing through the getter and if it is inside a valid session.

Comment: @NidhalRouissi read the last part of my answer: *`User user` in `Location` will only be retrieved when being accessing through the getter and **if it is inside a valid session***.

Comment: Now getting this exception :  org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session 

I am using a CrudRepository to avoid going into manual methods implementation as much as possible, is there a way to decide where to get the User object or not just by changing the query ?

Comment: @NidhalRouissi if you need it, retrieve the `User` while still being inside the session. Usually, the session/transaction should be at service level, not at repository level, so in the service layer you can define if you want/need to access to the desired field.

Comment: Ok that is a road to follow, but what is the point of using JOIN in JPQL queries if the User object is always loaded ?